# Reduce Font line height in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

After Xcode updated to 15, Apple has made `._lineHeightMultiple(_:)` internal in SwiftUI, thus removed such possibility to reduce the font `line height` below the default value.

How can we reduce the line height now in SwiftUI with the updated Swift and Xcode 15?

[image]

Comment: I think you'd need an `AttributedString` with an appropriate `NSParagraphStyle`.

Comment: Unfortunately SwiftUI just ignores line height which I set in AttributedString. Tried this already, and was shocked it does not work.

Comment: @Sweeper Maybe you can share your way? I have tried to convert AttributedString to NSAttributedString